# Getting the subject line in gmail api - javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, email, gmail-api

I'm trying to get the subject line from an email using the gmail API. I have the email back and tried following the documentation. I get an array of Headers back but the place holder for the subject line is different in each email.

How can I always get the Subject header back?

Right now I'm specifying the element in the array like so:

`var parsed5 = resp.payload.headers[1].name;`

However I don't want to have to specify the element of the area, is there a way to just get the right stuff based on the header name instead of the element?

Comment: That's the format of the response and you will have to write code to find the specific header.

Comment: I figured out a better way to do it, there's a parameter in the api call to just grab specific headers, so I just grabbed the three that I wanted. Much easier to deal with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the subject like that :

```
for (var headerIndex = 0; headerIndex < resp.payload.headers.length; headerIndex++) {
                if (resp.payload.headers[headerIndex].name == 'Subject') {
                    relateMailDetail.openMailSubject = msg.payload.headers[headerIndex].value;
                }
                if (resp.payload.headers[headerIndex].name == 'From') {
                    relateMailDetail.from = msg.payload.headers[headerIndex].value;
                }
                if (resp.payload.headers[headerIndex].name == 'Date') {
                    relateMailDetail.recieveDate = msg.payload.headers[headerIndex].value;
                }
                if (resp.payload.headers[headerIndex].name == 'To') {
                    relateMailDetail.to = msg.payload.headers[headerIndex].value;
                }
                if (resp.payload.headers[headerIndex].name == 'Cc') {
                    relateMailDetail.cc = msg.payload.headers[headerIndex].value;
                }
                if (resp.payload.headers[headerIndex].name == 'Reply-To') {
                    relateMailDetail.replyTo = msg.payload.headers[headerIndex].value;
                }
            }
```

Comment: You don't need loop over all data, please add `metadataHeaders=Subject`, so you will get only `Subject` info in `payload.header`

Answer (score 0):

So my solution was just using some of the api parameters in the call to only get what I wanted, so I didn't have to go through and find everything.

Comment: Example would be nice